# bx slider with single and multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, bxslider

I am using jQuery bx slider.
When I use three images in li I see three dots,
but when I use **one image it should not show one dot**.
I understood using `pager: false` will hide the dots,
but I am using only one js code so this should change dynamically.
I am trying to implement in my CMS where I am trying to change it into single and multiple images.
Can you tell me how to fix it?

http://bxslider.com/

Providing code below
https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/blob/master/jquery.bxslider.js

```
var populatePager = function(){
            var pagerHtml = '';
            var pagerQty = getPagerQty();
            // loop through each pager item
            for(var i=0; i < pagerQty; i++){
                var linkContent = '';
                // if a buildPager function is supplied, use it to get pager link value, else use index + 1
                if(slider.settings.buildPager && $.isFunction(slider.settings.buildPager)){
                    linkContent = slider.settings.buildPager(i);
                    slider.pagerEl.addClass('bx-custom-pager');
                }else{
                    linkContent = i + 1;
                    slider.pagerEl.addClass('bx-default-pager');
                }
                // var linkContent = slider.settings.buildPager && $.isFunction(slider.settings.buildPager) ? slider.settings.buildPager(i) : i + 1;
                // add the markup to the string
                pagerHtml += '<div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="' + i + '" class="bx-pager-link">' + linkContent + '</a></div>';
            };
            // populate the pager element with pager links
            slider.pagerEl.html(pagerHtml);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple javascript that will see how many dots are there and if it is less than 2(i.e 1) , it will hide that dot.

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('bx-pager-link');
    if(elements.length < 2){
     for (var i in elements) {
      if (elements.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        elements[i].style.display= 'none';
      }
     }
    }
```

Tested on http://bxslider.com/